# Replacing Line Iem in Xpath

Tags: c#, .net, regex, xpath

I have a line item like :

```
//FirstString/Second[001]/LastString
```

I need to replace [001] to [002] using Xpath.

After replacement the line item should look like :

```
//FirstString/Second[002]/LastString
```

I tried this in C# as follows :

```
   if (xpath.Contains("/Second") && xpath.Contains("["))
      {
        xpath = xpath.Remove(xpath.IndexOf("[")).Trim();
        xpath = xpath.Replace("Second", "Second[002]");

      }
```

But it is not working properly.

The result that I am getting : `//FirstString/Second[002]`

Instead of `//FirstString/Second[002]/LastString`

Any thoughts?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex solution:

```
var input = "//FirstString/Second[001]/LastString";

var result = Regex.Replace(input, @"(?<=Second\[)\d+(?=\])", "002");
```

---

```
string[] input = {
                        "//FirstString/Second[001]/LastString", 
                        "FirstString/Second[003]/LastString", 
                        "FirstString/Second[004]/LastString"
                    };

var result = input.Select(s => Regex.Replace(s, @"(?<=Second\[)\d+(?=\])", "002"));

foreach (var s in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Comment: If I have multiple lines like follows : //FirstString/Second[001]/LastString , FirstString/Second[003]/LastString, FirstString/Second[004]/LastString  and I want to replace [001], [003] and [004] with [002] in each like item. How I am going to do that?Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I tried this and it works for multiple line items :     if (xpath.Contains("/Second") && xpath.Contains("["))
                        {
                                                      xpath = Regex.Replace(xpath, @"(?<=Second\[)\d+(?=\])", "002"); 

                        }

Comment: @Dhruba, You're welcome! At SO the best way to say "thanks" is mark as answer or upvote :-)

Answer (score 0):

To complete Kirill's answer, the problem with your solution is the line:

```
xpath = xpath.Remove(xpath.IndexOf("[")).Trim();
```

By doing that, your line "//FirstString/Second[001]/LastString" becomes "//FirstString/Second" since Remove(int32), as written on MSDN, deletes all the characters from this string beginning at a specified position and continuing through the last position.

You should have tried sth like

```
xpath = xpath.Remove(xpath.IndexOf("["), "[001]".Length).Trim();
```

But clearly the solution with Regular expressions is much better.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [string.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx).

```
var oldXpath = "//FirstString/Second[001]/LastString";
var newXPath = oldXpath.Replace("001","002");
```